# Draw a rectangle with naming all vertices and labeling all sides

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a rectangle with name of all four vertices and label on all four sides ?

[image: rectangle with label on all 4 sides and vertices names]

Comment: Why should you just provide a picture? Why not show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=2]
    \hspace{-2cm}
    \draw 
    (0,0)node[left]{P}  to node[left]{1cm}      ++(0,1)node[left]{Q}
                        to node[above]{7cm}     ++(7,0)node[right]{R}
                        to node[right]{1cm}     ++(0,-1)node[right]{S}
                        to node[below]{7cm}     (0,0)        
    ;
    
\end{circuitikz}    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) -| node[pos=0,left]{P} node[pos=.25,above]{7\,cm}
  node[pos=.5,right]{Q} node[pos=.75,right]{1\,cm}
  ++(7,-1) -|  node[pos=0,right]{R} node[pos=.25,below]{7\,cm}
  node[pos=.5,left]{S} node[pos=.75,left]{1\,cm} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\psset{yunit=2cm, linejoin=1}
 \begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.25)(7.5,1.25)
 \pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PosAngle={180,0,0,180}](0,1){P}(7,1){Q}(7,0){R}(0,0){S}
 \psframe(P)(R)
 \pcline(P)(Q)\naput{7\,cm}
 \pcline(Q)(R)\naput[nrot=:U]{1\,cm}
 \pcline(R)(S)\naput{7\,cm}
 \pcline(S)(P)\naput[nrot=:U]{1\,cm}
  \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, minimum width=5cm, minimum height=1cm,
    label=\si{7}{cm},
    label=below:\si{7}{cm},
    label=right:\si{1}{cm},
    label=left:\si{1}{cm},
    label={[inner sep=1pt]north east:Q},
    label={[inner sep=1pt]north west:P},
    label={[inner sep=1pt]south east:R},
    label={[inner sep=1pt]south west:S}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]